XAMMP is not showing errro
I was working on code but XAMPP is not showing my custom error messages, rather it is showing the default error of
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Here is my sample code
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_php";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("There is some issue with this connection: " . $con->connect_error);
}
$num='abc';
$desc='some issue';
$solution='solution';
$status='status';



$qry = "INSERT INTO Complaint3 (C_Number, C_Desc, C_Solution, C_Status) VALUES ('$num '$desc', '$solution', '$status')";

if ($con->query($qry) === TRUE) {
    echo "successful";
} else {
    echo "Issue: " . $qry . "<br>" . $con->error;
}


$con->close();
?>

I am expecting to get this error messages
echo "Issue: " . $qry . "<br>" . $con->error;
